# Why does my play-button not work?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

Why does the code below not trigger the play-function in my script?
Don't understand why not, using the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BeUFb/) and it works fine there..
I decided to put in my whole index.php in here just because if there's something disturbing it all to work that I don't see. Anyone experiencing the same problem and managed to solve it? Please let me know how then!

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<title>Dungeon Runner</title>
<script>
//youtube script
//youtube script
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '244',
        width: '434',
        videoId: 'AkyQgpqRyBY',  // youtube video id
        playerVars: {
            'autoplay': 0,
            'rel': 0,
            'showinfo': 0
        },
        events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

onPlayerStateChange = function (event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        $('.start-video').fadeIn('normal');
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '.start-video', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut('normal');
    player.playVideo();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="topbar">
 
  <div class="topbar_content">
   <div class="topbar_left">
    <a href="http://playdungeonrunner.com"><img src="css/img/logo.png"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="topbar_right">
   
    <a href="http://playdungeonrunner.com" class="menu">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#" class="menu">About</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="http://forum.playdungeonrunner.com" class="menu">Forum</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/438330" class="menu">Steam Store</a>
   
   </div>
  </div>
 
 </div>
 
 
 
 <div class="container">
 
  <!--<iframe class="trailer" width="630" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4UHfocC1i54?autoplay=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&volume=0?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
 <div id="player"></div>
 <button class="start-video">Start Video</button>
  
  <div class="container_text">
   <p>Dungeon Runner is a 2D platformer with a high quality modern-retro design. The game is based on surviving several levels and passing them. Levels are set into chapters. 
   Each chapter provides more difficult levels.</p>
   <p>You're playing as Bjorg, a cave discoverer who's fallen into a adventure that nobody can imagine. You will be facing off monsters, puzzles and obstacles that you will need to pass in order to make 
   it to the next dungeon. Once you've passed all the levels, you can finally get out of this hell-hole that once was believed to be the greatest challenge for a cave enthusiast.</p>
   <br /><br />
   
   <div class="twitter_left">
    <a href="http://twitter.com/dungeonrungame" class="twitter"><h2><img src="css/img/twitter.png"> Twitter / @dungeonrungame</h2></a>
    <p><i>Follow the game's twitter for the latest updates and a easy way to get in contact with the dev(s)!</i></p>
   </div>
   <div class="twitter_right">
    <a href="http://twitter.com/hyprCSGO" class="twitter"><h2><img src="css/img/twitter.png"> Twitter / @hyprCSGO</h2></a>
    <p><i>Check out my own twitter account for exclusive sneak-peeks of future updates and how the game development is going!</i></p>
   </div>
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="container_right">
   <img src="css/img/enemies.png">
  </div>
  
 </div>
 
 <div class="footr">
  <div class="footr_content">
   <div style="float: left;">Copyright &copy; 2016 Jonathan Öhrström &bull; The game is available for PC/Mac/Linux. Steam required.</div>
   <div style="float: right;"><a href="mailto:press@playdungeonrunner.com" class="footer">Press</a>
    &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; 
   <a href="mailto:support@playdungeonrunner.com" class="footer">Contact</a>
    &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; 
   <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/dungeonrunnergame" class="footer" target="_blank">Steam Group</a></div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `java != javascript`

Comment: when you view the console what errors are you getting?

Comment: @AdrianDavidSmith Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, it says there's something wrong with this line:
$(document).on('click', '.start-video', function () {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add JQuery to your document and it should solve it...

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<title>Dungeon Runner</title>
...
</head>
```

JSFiddle by default adds this to their fiddles unless you explicitly tell it not to.

Comment: that did it! Thank you

Comment: @Condolent No problem! For future, if you ever get an error in your console that says '$ is not defined', you are not adding JQuery to your document OR you are trying to use JQuery operations or functions BEFORE you add JQuery to your document. It is always best practise to have it as one as your first imports/references in your documents. Glad I could help, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

add jquery before call

```
$(document).on('click', '.start-video', function () {
...
```

For example:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//youtube script
//youtube script
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
...
```